# AWS S3 response FAILED, even though file is fully uploaded

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm just trying to upload an image to S3 via an Android app. What I concluded so far is that images that are bigger than 5MB are uploaded without a problem, however, images that are smaller than 5MB are *FULLY UPLOADED* and can be downloaded from S3 manually, however, the response i get is FAILED. I just want to remind you that 5MB is the bottom threshold for issuing a multipart request (SDK uploads using multipart automatically when the file is above 5MB, I checked this in their code).

I also checked the md5 sum by hand, and the sums from two files (uploaded and selected for upload) *MATCH*.

I tested uploading small images using a AWS S3 CLI and it works without a problem.

This is the exception I get:

`AmazonClientException: Unable to verify integrity of data upload.  Client calculated content hash didn't match hash calculated by Amazon S3.  You may need to delete the data stored in Amazon S3.`

These are the libraries I am using:

`com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:$version`

`com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:$version`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's 5 GB, not 5 MB. With a single PUT, you can upload objects up to 5 GB in size. 5 MB is the minimum size of object that you can upload using multipart.

Comment: @jarmod - well, there is a "5 MB" limit in the context of S3 multi-part uploads: it's the smallest size acceptable for a part, other than the last part (which can be smaller than 5MB). The 5 GB limit you mention is the upper limit of a part size. So, there's both.

Comment: I wasn't clear. I meant what you said. Editing the question.

Comment: The symptoms suggest that either the hash that you sent with that part wasn't correct, or the transmission was corrupted. I'd guess the former to be much more likely.

Comment: I'm just passing a file to a library. This implementation worked for months and suddenly stopped. Any way to debug this on S3 console or something?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the problem was that bucket where images were uploaded was encrypted, as soon as we created a new unencrypted bucket, the uploads were fine. 
It seems that hash of two files was different because one hash calculation was done on an encrypted file and one on an unencrypted file. It seems (although I'm not completely sure) that multipart request just bypasses the md5 checksum check.

Important to mention, this was only happening while using the Android SDK, the iOS one works fine (don't know what are the exact differences in implementation, I could maybe update on that later).

It worked for months before the encryption was introduced.

I will investigate this issue further and notify AWS support if there is a reason for that.

Comment: I don't see how bucket encryption would make any difference so it would be interesting to learn what you find out. Which variant of SSE were you using?

Comment: I don't see that either. I'm just communicating what happened. We've tested this multiple times on multiple buckets, works every time.

The SSE that was used was AWS-KMS

Comment: Did you have any more insights on this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I am no longer working on this project. From what I hear from my colleagues, the issue has been resolved, although I don't know the specifics of how